# How do I display only the time in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, time

This is the code I have now:

```
Sub Page_Load
    lbl1.Text="The date and time is " & now()
End Sub
```

I want to modify `now()` to display only the time, without the date. How do I do this?

Comment: How much research did you do before asking this question?..

Comment: I wonder if the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime_members(v=vs.90).aspx) for `DateTime()` might contain an answer for you?  Maybe there is even a __property__ that contains what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

It should rather be

```
Sub Page_Load
    lbl1.Text = String.Format("The date and time is {0:t}", DateTime.Now)
End Sub
```

Or use `{0:T}` for "Long time pattern". [Here is a list of patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).